# Flutter move ListView items alignment is wrong

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I align these list items to have the icons on the far left instead of centered?

[image: Layout]

```
class HeaderRowListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> _listData = List<int>.generate(4, (i) => i);
  final List<Image> _list_images_trophys = [
    Image.network("https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/252-2524925_trophy-gold-medal-award-prize-achievements-clipart-png.png", height: 200, width:  200,),
    Image.network("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKnemmKgJOG_3OSk89VHtpTVAUGN1Nagcvgw&usqp=CAU", height: 200, width:  200,),
    Image.network("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1Ee4DhiFLB8CrzquwmJjcZepednxWN6E8oQ&usqp=CAU", height: 200, width:  200,),
    Image.network("https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/570-5705065_xbox-controller-clip-art.png", height: 200, width:  200,),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: _listData.map((i) {
          return i == 0
              ? Column(
                children: [
                  Image.network("https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/252-2524925_trophy-gold-medal-award-prize-achievements-clipart-png.png", height: 200, width:  200,),
                  Text("11/50",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Container(
            color: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(.8),
            child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Trophy",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          ),
                ],
              )
              : Column(
                children: [

                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ListTile(
            leading:   _list_images_trophys[i],
            title: Text("Achievement $i"),
          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple cases, setting  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` will fix the issue.

A ListTile is a basic built-in widget that can only be a particular height, and seems like we can't provide leading height:200 .

In this case we can use `Row` to create custom Card, in this case replace `ListTile` with Row. So the else state will be

```dart
       : Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          _list_images_trophys[i],
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ), // the space between image and text
                          Text("Achievementx $i"),
                        ],
                      ),
```

**Full-Widget**

```dart
class HeaderRowListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> _listData = List<int>.generate(4, (i) => i);
  final List<Image> _list_images_trophys = [
    Image.network(
      "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/252-2524925_trophy-gold-medal-award-prize-achievements-clipart-png.png",
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
    Image.network(
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKnemmKgJOG_3OSk89VHtpTVAUGN1Nagcvgw&usqp=CAU",
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
    Image.network(
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1Ee4DhiFLB8CrzquwmJjcZepednxWN6E8oQ&usqp=CAU",
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
    Image.network(
      "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/570-5705065_xbox-controller-clip-art.png",
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _list_images_trophys.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => i == 0
              ? Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                      "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/252-2524925_trophy-gold-medal-award-prize-achievements-clipart-png.png",
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Text("11/50",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(.8),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Trophy",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          _list_images_trophys[i],
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ), // the space between image and text
                          Text("Achievementx $i"),
                        ],
                      ),

                      // ListTile(
                      //   dense: true,
                      //   leading: SizedBox(
                      //     height: 200,
                      //     child: _list_images_trophys[i],
                      //   ),
                      //   title: Text("Achievementx $i"),
                      // ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for your case(for small images):

```dart
Column(
    children: [
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),// padding
                child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,//remove padding for list
                    leading: SizedBox(
                        child: _list_images_trophys[I],
                        height: 50.0, // image size
                        width: 50.0, // image size
                        ),
                    title: Text("Achievement $i"),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ],
    );
```

if you need big images, remove leading from ListTile:

```dart
title: Row(
           children: [
           _list_images_trophys[i],
           SizedBox(width: 6.0),
           Text("Achievement $i"),
         ],
),
```

This makes sense if you want to allow tap events on ListTile, then you will have reveal animation and other features of ListTile. If you don't need it, so just using a Row instead of ListTile will be a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start`  to the column widget which holds the align widget of listTile.